# Refreshing Height of bxslider slide with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have 2 slides of the bxslider and one of them has multiple "tabs" that load or hide content. Without refreshing the entire page, is there a way to change the height of the slide window on the fly?

Here's the slider I am working with: http://www.otse.org/slider-test/

Essentially, I'd want to add an action to the labels that are used for the subcategory buttons.

Comment: Hi DaPeters, did you find any answer for this query ? If yes, please add solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your `bxslider` you need to pass `adaptiveHeight: true`

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

See the bxSlider documentation example [here](http://bxslider.com/examples/slideshow-adaptive-height).

Comment: I've done that - when slides are changed (going from slide 1 to 2, or 2 to 1) the height adapts to the new slide's content. However, the height does *not* adapt when the dynamic content within an individual slide is changed.

Comment: @DaPeters Did you find a solution for this? I'm wondering about the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I came upon  a similar problem where when the user click on some of the html text of the content of bxslider, an textarea would replace the content and the height of the slider will need to change. I ended up doing this,

```
   $('.best_in_place').click(function(){
        var height = $(this).closest('li').css('height'); 
        $('.bx-viewport').css("height",height);

    });
```

I think you could replace .best_in_place with whatever class or id of your tab and change the height of the .bx-viewport based on your hide/show content.

my html:

```
<ul id="reviews" class="bxslider">
   <li class='review-item'></li>
   <li class='review-item'></li>
   <li class='review-item'></li> 
</ul>
```

(The list item contents are loaded dynamically with Ajax)